# Woocommerce 3.0.3 lightbox doesn't work

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a shop website with woocommerce 3.0.3 and on product detail page using default woocommerce templates, there is an issue with lightbox about clicking on the main image or gallery images. The site redirects me to a page with the image link instead of showing the lightbox.

Comment: Questions seekingn debugging help are off-topic and even if they were on-topic we could not determine what is wrong with your site. My best guess is you have a javascript error, probably due to an outdated theme template, but that's a total guess. You can switch to TwentySeventeen and disable plugins to isolate the issue.

Comment: I don't know whether its a known issue with woocommerce because I can't see any error in console. I switched to twenty sixteen and still popup seems not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. In latest version woocommerce-3.0.3, lightbox is replaced with photosswipe. Photoswipe is disabled in my theme. It works only if the theme add support like `add_theme_support('wc-product-gallery-lightbox')` then it works like a charm

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work, for me at least.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to add these lines in your function.php file and your lightbox (photoswipe) will work absolutely fine.

```
if(class_exists('WooCommerce')){
    add_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-zoom' );
    add_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-lightbox' );
    add_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-slider' );
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not only the missing `add_theme_support('wc-product-gallery-lightbox')`

If the DOM structure is not the same as the updated files: product-thumbnail.php and product-image.php - then the add_theme_support function won't help you.

Copy these files from WooCommerce plugin to your theme, and it should work.

Comment: Where do I copy that files on my theme?

Comment: Login to your FTP folder, and go to **/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/** and copy those files to **/wp-content/themes/YOURTHEME/woocommerce/**

Remember to keep the same structure, or your files won't work.